# Changing colors in geom_scatterpie

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Is there any way to change the colors in ggplot2 geom_scatterpie to anything other than the typical turquoise and coral?

I have scatter pies with two colors, but I want to change them to something else. Below is the code I'm using

```
map <- map +
  geom_scatterpie(data=cluster_10,
              aes(x=long, y=lat, r=sqrt(n)*radius_reduction),
              cols=c("northern","southern"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual in `ggplot2` you could set your desired colors via `scale_fill_manual`:

Using a minimal repdroducible example based on `usmap`:

```r
library(usmap)
#> Warning: package 'usmap' was built under R version 4.2.3
library(ggplot2)
library(scatterpie)
#> Warning: package 'scatterpie' was built under R version 4.2.3

cluster_10 <- data.frame(
  region = c("AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "IA"),
  northern = c(25, 45, 45, 60, 75),
  southern = c(45, 50, 45, 20, 15)
)

states <- us_map("states")

centroids <- usmapdata::centroid_labels("states")[c("x", "y", "abbr")]
names(centroids) <- c("long", "lat", "abbr")

cluster_10 <- merge(cluster_10, centroids, by.x = "region", by.y = "abbr", all.x = TRUE)

pal_color <- c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3")

plot_usmap() +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(long, lat, group = region),
    data = cluster_10, cols = c("northern", "southern"),
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_color) +
  theme(legend.position = "left")
```

[image]